# Get Location Permission from User in Android App

Tags: android, android-studio, location, android-permissions

I am implementing Access Location from user.Following is my Code. My problem is When I am clicking on Location permission it not getting the location.Bt when i am manually turn on the location from setting after that it giving me the location.My requirement is i Want compulsory check the Location permission from my App i.e. (it goes to setting and turn on location) .I gave all Permission in AndroidMeanifest file.And following is my SpashScreen.

```
package com.example.sbaapp;
public class SpashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog;

    String[] perms = {"android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION", "android.permission.READ_SMS"};
    int permsRequestCode = 200;





    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_spash_screen);
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SpashScreen.this, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_DayNight_DarkActionBar);

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext());

        //requestPermissions(perms, permsRequestCode);



        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if(!CheckPermissions()){
                requestPermissions(perms,permsRequestCode);
            }
        }


    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private boolean CheckPermissions() {
        int LocationPermission=checkSelfPermission(perms[0]);
        int ReadSmsPermission=checkSelfPermission(perms[1]);

        Log.d("Inside Permission","");

        return LocationPermission== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ReadSmsPermission==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

    }


 @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();


        SubscribeToTopic();
        if (new SessionManager(getApplicationContext()).ISLOGIN()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SpashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SpashScreen.this, Activity_home.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            }, 60000);
        }
    }
    private void SubscribeToTopic() {
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("SBASURVEY")
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        String msg = "SuccessGeneralNot";
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            msg = "Failed";
                        }
                        Log.d("TopicstatusForGeneral", msg);

                    }
                });

    }

   @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int permsRequestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults){

        switch(permsRequestCode){

            case 200:

                boolean locationAccepted = false;
                boolean smspermissionaccepted=false;

                if(grantResults.length>=2) {
                    locationAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    smspermissionaccepted = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                }else if(grantResults.length>=1){
                    if(permissions[0].equals("android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION")){
                        locationAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                        smspermissionaccepted=true;
                    }else {
                        locationAccepted=true;
                        smspermissionaccepted = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    }
                }
                if(!(locationAccepted || smspermissionaccepted)){

                    new AlertDialog.Builder(SpashScreen.this).setMessage("You Need Accept Both the permissions In Order to Smooth Working Of Application Functionality")
                            .setPositiveButton("Ok",new SpashScreen.OkListenerForBoth())
                            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",null)
                            .create()
                            .show();
                }else if(!locationAccepted){

                    new AlertDialog.Builder(SpashScreen.this).setMessage("You Need Accept This Location Based permissions In Order to Smooth Working Of Application Functionality")
                            .setPositiveButton("Ok",new SpashScreen.OkListenerForLocation())
                            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",null)
                            .create()
                            .show();
                }

                else if(!smspermissionaccepted){

                    new AlertDialog.Builder(SpashScreen.this).setMessage("You Need Accept This SMS Read permissions In Order to Smooth Working Of Application Functionality")
                            .setPositiveButton("Ok",new SpashScreen.OkListenerForSmS())
                            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",null)
                            .create()
                            .show();
                }

                break;

        }

    }
    public class OkListenerForBoth implements AlertDialog.OnClickListener{

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            requestPermissions(perms,permsRequestCode);
        }
    }
    public class OkListenerForLocation implements AlertDialog.OnClickListener{

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{perms[0]},permsRequestCode);
        }
    }

    public class OkListenerForSmS implements AlertDialog.OnClickListener{

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{perms[1]},permsRequestCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: first of all read sms permission the app will be rejected at play store

Comment: yes i gave all permission in Meanifest.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below it will open a location request dialog and then you will be able to get the location.

```
if (googleApiClient == null) {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
        googleApiClient.connect();

        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true);  

        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                final Status status = result.getStatus();
                final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                          break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:

                        try {

                            status.startResolutionForResult(
                                    getActivity(), 1000);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:

                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What is googleApiClient. I am getting error at googleApiClient and getActivity() @Ajeett

Comment: In Android Studio, go to File -> Project Structure.
Go to the dependencies tab.
On the right hand side add a 'Library Dependency'.
Type "com.google.android.gms:play-services" into the searchbox and pick the appropriate dependency.

Comment: `getActivity()` is the context. If you are using the code in activity you can use `getApplicationContext()` or `getContext()` or this.yourActivityName

Comment: I am  adding com.google.android.gms:play-service:9.8.0but getting error... class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zza not found@Ajeett

Comment: problem is with version code you are using, you will have to change it and check you can check it for 10.0.1 version

Comment: Also have you implemented this line in your gradle? `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' `

Comment: yes, i put the the above dependency still getting me same error@Ajeett

Comment: what about the version changing try doing it. There is an issue with it only

Comment: com.google.android.gms:play-service:9.8.0 to  com.google.android.gms:play-service:10.0.1 @Ajeett